# setListAdapter is not working

Tags: android

I am following exact steps of an online tutorial, I checked every other places,
this gives me no errors, however, when it comes to this activity, instead of a menu, it gives me a blank white page.
Would you please help me here to figure out what's the problem?!
Thanks. :)

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = { "startingPoint", "example1", "example2"
        , "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,
        PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.thenewboston.travis." + cheese);        
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload [`onCreate(Bundle,PersistableBundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) is only for API level 21 and up. For pre-21, you need `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Change the signature from

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,
    PersistableBundle persistentState) {
```

to

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfectly. :)
Thank you.